# HTML table coded before img src but browser showing image before table. Help fix?

Tags: html

this is my first posted question. My html index file is written out with table tags first and img src last in the body. However, my browser shows the image first and then the table. How do I fix this? Here's the code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset ="utf-8">
        <title>Levi's Biography</title>
    <!-- lines 6 through 11 are simply added for developing the page to a future standard -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="mybio.css">

        <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

          <table border="4px">
            <thead>
                <tr border="3px">
                    <th colspan="4"><h2>Levi Donaldson</h2></th>

            </thead>

            <tbody>             
                <tr>
                    <td>Born</td>
                    <td>Grew up</td>
                    <td>Hobbies</td>
                    <td>Foods</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Moenci, AZ</td>
                    <td>Mesa, AZ
                        <br>
                    Wasilla, AK
                        <br> 
                    Eagar, AZ
                        <br> 
                    Cliff, NM
                    </td>

                    <td>Quality family time
                        <br> 
                    Traveling
                        <br> 
                    Fishing
                        <br> 
                    Cooking
                        <br> 
                    Passive income streams
                        <br> 
                    Creating things or improving their designs
                    </td>

                    <td>A great steak
                        <br> 
                    Sushi (with scallops if possible)
                        <br> 
                    Brazilian rice and beans
                        <br> 
                    Home grown fruit
                        <br> 
                    Fresh garden veggies and herbs
                        <br> Cheesecake (but for heavens sake, NO New York style)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_b3dSgzaqFKs/SRfDqJxbSOI/AAAAAAAAADc/iNvyqMQqzKs/S220/katie%26levi2+001.jpg"/>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close your table with a `</table>` tag. So the img is being moved. Just put a `</table>` tag after `</tbody>` but before img tag.

Comment: No problem. It's easy to miss. I like to use a helpful editor to help me match by open and close tags. I usually use Sublime Text 3 for most things. Just syntax highlighting and highlighting of matching close tab can help catches these typos.